# установка ограничения на поворот на определённый угол

Tags: unity3d

Часть скрипта, поворачивающая объект:

```
float AngleRotate = Time.deltaTime * RotateSpeed * Input.GetAxis("MoveTower");
Tower.transform.Rotate(0, 0, AngleRotate);
```

Он работает, но обьект залазит в текстуру, нужно ограничение

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)
Он принимает три параметра:

- float (int) value - значение
- float (int) min - минимальное значение
- float (int) max - максимальное значение

Если value < min, то функция возвращает min
Если min < vaue < max, то функция возвращает value
Если value > max, то функция возвращает max